How can i change the values of a cloumnGroup type="header" in JSF Primefaces?
I have this columnGroup in a datatable:
<p:columnGroup style="width: fit-content" type="header">
the type "header" has a default padding which I'm trying to change. How can i achieve this?
I tried to to access this with a styleclass in the datatable. But it doesnt change anything at all.
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-datatable ui-datatable-sticky ui-widget {
        padding: 0rem !important;
        width: auto !important;
        width: 2rem;

    }

<p:dataTable

value="#{}"
var="" showGridlines="true" size="small"
emptyMessage="" stickyHeader="true"
styleClass="ui-datatable"
style=" margin-top: 0.3rem; font-size: 100%; padding: 0rem; width:auto"
selectionPageOnly="true" rowSelectMode="none">
<p:columnGroup style="width: fit-content" type="header">
...
...
</p:columnGroup>
</p:dataTable>

